# R: How do I create a new row, then add some cells from the previous row, iterating through the whole table like this?

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to take each cell from V9-13 here and create a new row below each existing row, adding the values from cells V9-13 to the new row. This means that row 1 will have values V1-V8, then the new row below it will have V9-V13 from row 1 in the V1-V5 columns of that row.

[Here's an image of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/389lR.png)

```
{

library("readxl")
library("dplyr")

text_data <- read.delim("C:\\Users\\Kavin Kadam\\Desktop\\UBC\\PCIGR\\IoliteOutlier\\Individual Answers_472.txt", skip=19, header=FALSE)

x<-(nrow(text_data))

for (i in 1:x) {
  text_data_refined<-dplyr::add_row(
    text_data,
    V1 = text_data$V9[i-1],
    V2 = text_data$V10[i-1],
    V3 = text_data$V11[i-1],
    V4 = text_data$V12[i-1],
    V5 = text_data$V13[i-1],
    .after = text_data_refined[i,]
    )
  }

}
```

The sample output would be as in this image - it takes the V9-V13 from the previous row and adds it to the new row here:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGqM0.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't most data or code as images. We don't want to have to retype everything just to try it.

Comment: I see, I will edit my question, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text_data<-as.matrix(text_data)
n<-nrow(text_data)

#initialize new matrix
new_data<-matrix(NA, nrow=2*n, ncol=8)

#fill values
new_data[seq(from=1, to=2*n, by=2), 1:8]<-text_data[,1:8]
new_data[seq(from=2, to=2*n, by=2), 1:5]<-text_data[,9:13]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a row identifer, use `bind_rows()`, and then arrange by that row identifier.

```
text_data <- text_data %>% mutate(id=row_number())
bind_rows(
  df %>% relocate(id),
  df %>% select(id, V9:V13) %>% rename_with(~c("id", paste0("V",1:5)))
) %>% arrange(id)
```

Comment: Another solution worked for me, but I just wanted to comment and thank you for taking the time and effort!